# What to use to put layout in activity Android?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have an activity that uses setContentView to initiate a listview, and then I have an If-Else condition. In the **If** part of the statement I use a simpleAdapter to place a new layout in the listview and other data from a cursor. In the **Else** part, I just want to put a sentence in a label to provide some information. How can I do that? I tried parameters and textview but they didn't work. I tried to put another setcontentView but it can't work either.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
```

doMySearch() is a cursor that extracts data from database based on a keyword input by user.

```
public void onPostExecute() {
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Int count = doMysearch().getCount;
If (count >= 1){
adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_results,
doMySearch(), new String[] {  
    DB.COL_NAME,
    DB.COL_CITY },
    new int[] { R.id.lblName, R.id.lblCity },
    0);

setListAdapter(adapter);
}
Else {
}
```

I just want a sentence that says "No data found" for the Else part. Thanks.

Comment: what's in your `layout.xml`

Comment: if u want to show two different view on layout and 2 different layout, then create 2 different activity?

Comment: can you show us some code? What exactly are you trying to display in the else branch? Should it also be structured like a list but with different info, or a completely different view? Is it possible, you want to display an empty text that says something like: "No data available?"

Comment: Wow, you should be writer, not a programmer. Wouldn't it be easier if you posted a code? :-)

Comment: @peshkira, yes, you are right, I just want to say "No data available." I just put up some codes. Thanks.

Comment: yeah guys, I just added the codes. Thanks.

Comment: if it is just for showing a view that there is no data available, you should use the setEmptyView method of the listview. @Gunhan answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear for me what you are asking but here we go.

There is empty view setting in ListView for empty lists, you have to add another empty view in your current layout. Then you will set the empty view layout in code like below:

```
//add to your layout
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="There is no item" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>


//set empty view
ListView listView = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.list);
LinearLayout emptyView = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.empty);
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it work as intended with the codes you provided, although with some changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the label doesn't show up because of the listview, right?`

EDIT:
Okay I think I get it now.
To keep it simple you could hide your ListView with `myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
Then make a premade Label visible with `myLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` that already holds your error-string.

The harder way you could make a StringArray, like this in (for example) the strings.xml

```
<string-array name="error">
        <item>No results found</item>
</string-array>
```

Then, in your else-block you can do somethink like that:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList); 
String[] content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.error); 
ArrayAdapter<String> typeList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_custom, content);
lv.setAdapter(typeList);
```